# will remain vs will be

Tags: grammar

Which of the below two sentences is more appropriate as for as the spoken English is concerned?

1.The school will remain closed until 7th June

2.The school will be closed until 7th June

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are appropriate, whether in spoken or written English, but they mean slightly different things.

1. Using *remain* indicates that the school is already closed and will continue to be closed until 7th June.
2. Using *be* indicates that from some unspecified time or date, the school will be closed until 7th June. It does not imply that the school is already closed.

Note that the word *below* in your question, which is a preposition, should come after *two sentences* rather than before. Alternatively, you might write: *..the following/next two sentences..*